# Изменить версию openssl в MAMP

Tags: openssl, mamp, tls

[Насколько я знаю](https://www.suse.com/communities/blog/tls-1-2/), `openssl 0.9.8` не работает с протоколом `tls 1.2`:

```
user@computer: /usr/bin/openssl version
OpenSSL 0.9.8zg 14 July 2015
user@computer: /usr/bin/openssl s_client -connect somesite.com:8443
CONNECTED(00000003)
write:errno=54
```

`8443` порт как раз работает по `tls 1.2`.

Но при этом `openssl 1.0.2` с описанным выше протоколом работает:

```
user@computer: openssl version         
OpenSSL 1.0.2d 9 Jul 2015
user@computer: openssl s_client -connect somesite.com:8443
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=2 C = US, O = "blah-blah" ...
....
```

В качестве сервера использую [MAMP](https://www.mamp.info/en/). В `phpinfo` говорится, что 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, как изменить версию `openssl` в `MAMP`?